# Enable always-on OTG on the Oppo Reno 6

Tags: usb-on-the-go, oppo

I found the command `adb shell settings put global oneplus_otg_auto_disable 0`  to make the OTG option always on on OnePlus 6/5T/5/3T/3 running OxygenOS.

How can I modify it to work on Oppo Reno 6?

Comment: Based on the settings name this is an OnePlus specific modification of Android. So the first question is if Oppo phones have something similar at all's and in detail if your phone has it. Your chances getting an answer may be higher if you post this in a forum where only Oppo phones and thus Oppo users are around.